# Uncaught TypeError: material.onBeforeRender is not a function

Tags: three.js

I am getting this error when I add my .glb model to the scene

```
Uncaught TypeError: material.onBeforeRender is not a function
at renderObject (three.js:19969:13)
at renderObjects (three.js:19960:6)
at renderScene (three.js:19900:34)
at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:19789:5)
at animate (main.js:78:12)
at main.js:84:7
```

and this is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Space Rocket Simulation</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    *{
        padding: 0 ;
        margin: 0 ;
     }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id = "webgl"></div>
    <script src="js/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script type = "module"src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use three.module.js but when I use it I get this error

> uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
> at OrbitControls.js:19:30
> at OrbitControls.js:1079:4 (anonymous) @ OrbitControls.js:19 (anonymous) @ OrbitControls.js:1079 main.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError:
> THREE is not defined
> at init (main.js:6:17)
> at main.js:110:1 init @ main.js:6 (anonymous) @ main.js:110

the whole main.js file

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
function init() {


  /*creating a new scene*/
    var scene = new THREE.Scene() ;


  /*creating a new variables value control panel*/
    var gui = new dat.GUI() ;


  /*creating a perspectiveCamera*/
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)
    camera.position.x = 1 ;
    camera.position.y = 2 ;
    camera.position.z = 5 ;



  /*the director*/
    var sphere , pointlight ;
    sphere = getSphere(0.05) ;//getting the sphere
    pointlight = getPointLight(3) ;//getting pointLight
    pointlight.position.y = 2 ;
    pointlight.position.x = 2 ;
    pointlight.add(sphere) ; //adding the sphere as a child to the pointLight
A

    /*adding models*/
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load( 'models/Rocket.glb', function ( glb ) {

        scene.add( glb.scene );

    }, undefined, function ( error ) {

        console.error( error );

    } );



   


    /*adding objects to the Scene*/
    scene.add(pointlight) ;
    gui.add(pointlight ,"intensity",0,10) ;
    gui.add(pointlight.position , "x" , 0 , 4) ; //creating a controller  for the pointLight X parameter ont the control panel
    gui.add(pointlight.position , "y" , 0 , 4) ; //as above
    gui.add(pointlight.position , "z" , 0 , 4) ;// as above
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)) ; //telling the camera to look at the point (0,0,0)
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer() ;
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true ;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight) ;
    renderer.setClearColor("rgb(120 , 120 , 120)") ;
    document.getElementById("webgl").appendChild(renderer.domElement) ;
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera , renderer.domElement) ;
    animate(renderer , scene , camera , controls) ;
}

/*Creating an animating scene*/
function animate(renderer , scene , camera , controls)
{
  renderer.render(scene , camera) ;


  controls.update() ;
  requestAnimationFrame(function()
    {
      animate(renderer , scene , camera , controls) ;
    }) ;
}

/*creating a pointlight*/
function getPointLight(intensity)
{
  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, intensity) ;
  light.castShadow = true ;
  light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048 ;
  light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048 ;
  return light ;
}

/*getting sphere*/
function getSphere(size)
{
  var geometry= new THREE.SphereGeometry(size , 24 , 24) ;
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color:"rgb(255 , 255 , 255)" ,
    }) ;

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry , material) ;
  return mesh ;

}
init() ;
```

Comment: From what you have shared so far it is not clear why the exception occurs. Do you mind demonstrating the issue with a live app?

Comment: nope no problem